# Assign value after when is called in haskell

Tags: haskell

The error must be so tiny in these few lines that I will not get it myselft.

Here is my code:

```
askName = do
  putStr "Type your name: "
  name <- getLine
  return name

sayHelloTo name = do
  when (null name) (name <- askName)
```

Apparently it gives an error:

```
1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:9:30: parse error on input `<-'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Any suggestion?

Edit 1.

Same if I write:

```
sayHelloTo name = do
  when (null name) (name2 <- askName)
```

Comment: You can't reassign the contents of a variable in Haskell.  Why are you trying to?

Comment: I would like to change the value if it is false, with a new value, can't I ?

Comment: ...No.  That's not how Haskell works.  What you could do is create a new variable initialized either with `name` or with a new string acquired from `askName`, though.

Comment: @haskellguy you're welcome to use the same name in multiple bindings in a `do` block, however later bindings simply shadow earlier ones

Comment: @haskellguy It seems like you're trying to drag in python's conception of mutable variable here. Using `(<-)` operator out of `do` expression is not allowable in Haskell. But even if you get `name` variable changed after call to `askName`, this change will not affect input parameter `name`: you will got a new value with same name. That means, your function `sayHelloTo` should return the value, in order you may use the result: `sayHelloTo name = if null name then askName else return name`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `name2 <-` syntax is part of do-notation and can only be used inside a `do` block. It is also *not* a variable assignment - under the hood it is just creating a callback function that has `name2` as a parameter

That is, the following code:

```
do
    name2 <- monadicOp
    ...things...
```

desugars into

```
monadicOp >>= (\name2 -> ...things... )
```

I hope this helps make it clear that you don't assign things or mutate them in Haskell.

anyway, to solve your particular problem, whay you could do is just use if-then-else (something that is actually equivalent to the `?:` ternary oerator) and return the appropriate value. For example, the following function uses recursion to ask for a name again and again until it is happy with the result

```
getNonEmptyName :: IO String
getNonEmptyName = do
    name <- getName
    if null name --note: indenting if statements in do blocks is tricky
       then getNonEmptyName
       else (return name)
```

or, without the do notation sugar:

```
getNonEmptyName = getName >>= (\name -> if (null name) then getNonEmptyName else (return name) )
```

This might be a bit moe different the what you are used to, but I guess you should be able to clear thing sup after you get how this is working. Basically `getNonEmptyName` is of type `IO String`, meaning it is an IO actioin IO action that yields a String when it is run. The if-then-else part is supposed to evaluate to an `IO String` value as well, since its value will be the return value of getNonEmptyName. This all works all right since in the first we do a recursive call to getNonEmptyName (and that gives an IP String value as desired) and in the else branch we promote a regular string value (name) to an IO String using the return function.

Answer (score 4):

It's not entirely clear what `sayHelloTo` is supposed to do or return -- it's certainly not going to modify `name` -- but at a guess, you might mean something like

```
 sayHelloTo :: String -> IO String
 sayHelloTo name
   | null name   = askName
   | otherwise   = return name
```